# How to add URI to a .bib file with a hyperlink?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, hyperref, natbib

How to add a URI to a bib file with a hyperlink so that anyone who clicks on it will be directed to the page displaying the thesis.

There does not appear to be a `uri` tag in the bibliography, so I tried making a custom field by adding the following to the preamble

```
\newcommand{\uri}[1]{\href{http://hdl.handle.net/#1}{URI: #1}}
```

but unfortunately it doesn't do anything.

These are the relevant packages in my preamble

```
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
```

Here is the code I'm using to add my bibliography in the document

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{References/references.bib}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
```

Comment: Exactly what setup are you using? It is a bit confusing when you tag this with both `biblatex` and `bibtex`.

Comment: Do you want the link to be clickable in the `.bib` file or in the Bibliography in the output file? (.pdf?)

Comment: @daleif I've added more text to indicate the packages I'm using. I added tags for multiple bib styles since I am open to any solution.

Comment: @Plergux I would like the link to be clickable in the pdf document generated. Basically I would like something like this in the references: A Student, Great Work. PhD Thesis. URI: 1234.5/12345

Comment: Then just add the url to the `note` field. Note that your `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}` will fail (wrong location) if the bibliography is more than one page. Use the `bibtocind` package to have the bibliography automatically included in the toc.

Comment: @daleif yes you're right, I hadn't thought of that. using `\href` in `note` works. however is it possible to define a custom `uri` field for a bib file?

Comment: It depends on what the bibtex style offers. If on the otherhand you are using `biblatex` then you have more free hands. But at the price of `biblatex` being a bit more complicated and it needs a difference programme than `bibtex` (it uses `biber`). Plus it is also not well known whether journals /arxiv supports biblatex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `natbib` with `plainnat` you can use

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
    \usepackage{natbib,hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Important,
  author       = "Doe, J.",
  title        = "Gnus and Gnats",
  journal      = "Gnus of the world",
  year         = "2020",
  volume       = "2456",
  number       = "1",
  pages        = "123--2567",
  url         = "https://tex.stackexchange.com",
}
\end{filecontents*}
\citet{Important}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```